# Bootstrap Popover when clicking on events

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-big-calendar

I'm looking to integrate something like Bootstrap Popover when clicking on events in react-big-calendar componenet; I think it is possible to achieve it by custom components; is there any example where it shows how I can integrate it with Bootstrap Popover and using custom components? And also if there is any other ways to achieve that, I appreciate it if you help.

Comment: can you share what you've tried so far ?

Comment: Here is my attempt: https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar/issues/871#issuecomment-538204177

there is a solution for modals but I could not find any solution for popover from any CSS frameworks.

Anyone knows any solution please?